# AEM ResourceResolver closure?

Tags: aem

I am using Sling ResourceResolver in my AEM code using two ways.

1. Getting it using ResourceResolverFactory.

   @Reference
    ResourceResolverFactory factory;
   ResourceResolver resolver = factory.getResourceResolver();

I use this ResourceResolver in finally block.

```
finally{
resolver.close();}
```

2. Getting it using SlingHttpServletRequest

   ResourceResolver resolver = request.getResourceResolver();

My question is do i need to close ResourceResolver obtained from SlingHttpServletRequest or as request terminates, it ResourceResolver will also be closed?

Answer (score 12):

The ResourceResolver we get from SlingHttpServletRequest is managed by container, we should not close it. As per the [official documentation](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html)

> A Resource Resolver has a life cycle which begins with the creation of
>   the Resource Resolver using **any of the factory methods** and ends with
>   calling the close() method. It is very important to call the close()
>   method once the resource resolver is not used any more to ensure any
>   system resources are properly clean up.

So the ResourceResolver  we get from factory should be managed by our own code. Also have a look at [this link.](https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/cq-development-patterns-sling-resourceresolver-and-jcr-sessions/) This gives good insight around ResourceResolver and Sessions which are important from Sling and JCR prespective

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you would not want to close ResourceResolver which you did not create. Or to be more specific: you should never close a ResourceResolver, which **session** *or* **livecycle** you don't handle. For example if you adapt to a ResourceResolver, you must not close it as the underlying session would be closed as well. The session handling is completely transparent so you need to trust the service vendor that the implementation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I still wasn't entirely clear on where the ownership of the resource resolver lies but having played around a bit while coding a component that accesses the JCR tree, it is clear that closing the resource resolver within a component causes problems. Even if I only access the JCR tree in component code where the resource resolver is open, there are other parts of the page processing that require the ResourceResolver to remain open and so I just get a page error.

Thinking about this logically, given that a page may contain multiple components, any of which may need access to the JCR tree, it would absolutely not be correct for one component to close the thread ResourceResolver as that would impact other components being rendered in the same request. The documentation and discussion is not especially clear on this but my understanding is that when a component gets the thread ResourceResolver from an adapted SlingHttpServletRequest then the ResourceResolver is owned and managed by the SlingServlet that handles the entire page (or other framework code).

It seems possible then that when coding a Sling servlet the ResourceResolver should be closed, but even then a thread ResourceResolver is obtained either from an injected factory or from the request and so I would suspect that it is still owned by framework code, and that the framework will either close it off after all processing is complete, or possibly the factory maintains a pool of open resource resolvers that are just allocated to request handling threads and then returned to the pool without being closed. I need to get hold of the AEM source to check.

I have seen examples of working sling servlets that close the resource resolver, but those appear to be using the deprecated getAdministrativeResourceResolver method rather than getThreadResourceResolver, so that may explain the difference.

Comment: As per the accepted answer, you should only close the resource resolve if you have opened it. Closing request level resource resolvers will cause issues. Admin resource resolvers (deprecated) are different as you create a new reference for your use when you call the getAdministrativeResourceResolver method therefore you are responsible to close it. Framework does not perform any cleanup for the resource resolvers opened by your thread and neither does it have any way to prevent your code from closing resource resolvers opened by request chain.

Comment: Chris - I liked the way you explained. I have similar problem and opened request here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593644/session-has-been-closed-after-closing-resource-resolver-object-in-aem Would you please share your input here ?

Comment: Ah thanks @ezhil - unfortunately I changed teams 3 years ago and haven't touched any of this stuff since, so although my answer kind of makes sense to me I'm totally out of touch with the detail. I will look at your question but I have to be honest, I'm really unlikely to have a clue! On the other hand, if you have any spring boot or Kafka questions then maybe I'm your man :-)

Comment: Ah, frustrating as I'm sure I have seen both the error messages you mentioned but it's just too hazy now. Really sorry, hope someone comes back with the right answer soon.

Comment: Thank you for your response Chris. No worries, I will explorer it

Comment: Good luck @ezhil

Answer (score 0):

When you, for example, use the resource resolver that is provided by the sling request and close that manually in your code, other services that are triggered later in the code cannot use it anymore. That mean you will get a lot of exception telling you the resource resolver is already closed.

The resource resolver that is provided by the request will automatically be closed when the request is "over".